# How to parse xml data

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am making an iPhone app, which calls an web API, and retrieves XML files. I have XML data that I need to parse, but I only need one element from the whole XML file. There may be multiple xml files loaded at once, but I still only need one element from each file. I am trying to use NSXMLParser to parse the data, but if there are any easier options, I am open to them. Does anyone know any good tutorials about how to do this, or know to explain it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: xpath will be helpful for you.

Comment: Is xpath a library that can be added to my project?

Comment: [Oreilly](http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html)

Comment: [CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/XPath)

Comment: There are 101 3rd party iOS XML Parsers. Many of them suck. I personally use GDataXmlNode.h/m (a DOM parser) from Google's GData library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both XMLParser and XPath to parse and each has its costs and benefits. XPath is fantastic if you know for a fact what the DOM path of the target object is. XMLParser allows for more flexibility in terms of iterating through the XML programmatically.

I would recommend both of these links:

[NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

[XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578619/creating-xpath-query-dynamically-using-touchxml-and-xcode)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do know the exact name of the element I want, so XPath sounds like it will be best. Is Xpath a library that I have to import into my project?

Comment: XPath is a standard. Look around for Hpple... it's an open source library that will let you leverage XPath pretty easily. There should be plenty of examples out there on how to use it.